# How to get postgres database cpu usage

Tags: postgresql

I need to get the database CPU usage using query

For example I get the database size using this function: pg_database_size('databaseName')

and for SQL Server, I use this query:

```
SELECT top 1 avg_cpu_percent  AS AverageCPUUsed,end_time
FROM sys.resource_stats
WHERE database_name = 'qa'
```

Any idea how to do this in postgres ?

Comment: Postgres doesn't provide such a metric

Comment: if your database is hosted on a cloud platform like AWS you can view CPU usage in cloudwatch. If it is self hosted on a Linux server you can check CPU stats using something like the top command